# python3's pipenv, is only creating python3 shell,even though the parameter --two is passed. .Do we need to install pipenv for both python?

Tags: python, pipenv

```
campaign_response sidvis$ pipenv --two shell
:
✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
:
(campaign_response) bash-3.2$
```

Now the pipenv campaign_response is setup! But it fails because of python3.6 dependencies.

```
(campaign_response) bash-3.2$ pipenv install x
Installing x…
Adding silverpop to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed! 
.
..
...
    from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/typing.py", line 133
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, *, _root=False):
```

And python3 comes as defaulty python:

```
(campaign_response) bash-3.2$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was happening was because pipenv was picking python3 pipenv.oops! 
you need to use a lib in python2 pipenv by passing it as:
python2 -m pipenv install x